# Timeout Excepetion no Android

Tags: java, android

Eu antes carregava minhas collections de uma forma que eu percebi que poderia da problema de desempenho, listando todos os registros por vez, agora criei usando um "lazy loading" e me da o erro TimeOut Exception

```
Query queryPosts = db.collection("collection").orderBy("fieldCollection", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
queryPosts.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        boolean havePosts = false;
        int i = 0;
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                i++;
                if (documentSnapshot.getData().get("postCommunity").equals(communityId)) {
                    havePosts = true;

                    Posts postsList = documentSnapshot.toObject(Posts.class);

                    postsArrayList.add(postsList);


                }

            }
            if (task.getResult().size() == i && !havePosts) {
                rvPosts.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                lblSeeAllPosts.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                titlePosts.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            postsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }
});
```

Dessa forma, ele demorava um tempo grande mas não dava TimeoutException

Pesquisando algumas coisas cheguei em uma forma de lista chamada LazyLoading, onde basicamente a medida que o usuário vai chegando no final do scroll, disparo mais um pouquinho do carregamento.

A minha ideia era fazer algo parecido com carregamento "server-side" do datatable do php

```
loadInitialVideos(communityId);
rvVideo.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
        int visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
        int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
        int firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        // Verifica se o usuário atingiu o final da lista
        if (visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition >= totalItemCount
                && firstVisibleItemPosition >= 0
                && totalItemCount >= limit) {
            loadMoreVideos(communityId); // Carrega mais posts
        }
    }
});
```

**METODOS QUE SÃO CRIADOS**

```
private void loadInitialVideos(String communityId) {
    if (!isLoadingVideos) { // Verifica se não estamos carregando posts atualmente
        isLoadingVideos = true; // Define isLoadingPosts como true para indicar que estamos carregando posts

        CollectionReference referenceVideos = db.collection("Videos");
        Query queryVideos = referenceVideos
                .whereEqualTo("videoCommunity", communityId)
                .orderBy("videoDateHora", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .limit(limit);

        queryVideos.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {

                        Videos videos = documentSnapshot.toObject(Videos.class);
                        videoArrayList.add(videos);


                    }
                    if (!task.getResult().isEmpty()) {
                        lastVisibleVideo = task.getResult().getDocuments().get(task.getResult().size() - 1);
                    }

                    videoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else{

                }
                isLoadingVideos = false;
            }
        });
    }
}

private void loadMoreVideos(String communityId) {
    if (!isLoadingVideos) { // Verifica se não estamos carregando posts atualmente
        isLoadingVideos = true; // Define isLoadingPosts como true para indicar que estamos carregando posts

        CollectionReference referenceVideo = db.collection("Videos");
        Query queryVideos = referenceVideo
                .whereEqualTo("videoCommunity", communityId)
                .orderBy("videoDateHora", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .limit(limit);
        if (lastVisibleVideo != null) {
            queryVideos = queryVideos.startAfter(lastVisibleVideo);
        }
        queryVideos.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {

                        Videos videos = documentSnapshot.toObject(Videos.class);
                        videoArrayList.add(videos);


                    }
                    if (!task.getResult().isEmpty()) {
                        lastVisibleVideo = task.getResult().getDocuments().get(task.getResult().size() - 1);
                    }

                    videoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else{

                }
                isLoadingVideos = false;
            }
        });
    }
```

**ERRO REPORTADO**

```
Optimistic bind failed.
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: [Optimistic Bind] Didn't bind to resolver in time!
    at com.android.server.pm.InstantAppResolverConnection.waitForBindLocked(InstantAppResolverConnection.java:160)
    at com.android.server.pm.InstantAppResolverConnection.bind(InstantAppResolverConnection.java:225)
    at com.android.server.pm.InstantAppResolverConnection.lambda$optimisticBind$0$com-android-server-pm-InstantAppResolverConnection(InstantAppResolverConnection.java:255)
    at com.android.server.pm.InstantAppResolverConnection$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```